# finding image in Sikuli X Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium, sikuli

I am having an issue trying to find an image on the screen, I tried doing it in two different ways and it doesn't seem to work for me.
I am trying to do this with Appium running on IOS simulator which shows up on the screen, so I don't see this being a problem of a screenshot being taken.

I am running MAC OSX El Capitan
I have imported the Sikuli X java API in my project

Do I need to also import the MAC Sikuli Library jar?

This is what I have tried so far:

1.

```
Screen s = new Screen();
Pattern test = new Pattern("/Users/ealiaj/Desktop/Automation/workspace/WheelsUp - IOS/screenshot.jpg");
try {
    s.find(test);
} catch (FindFailed e) {

}
```

2.

```
Screen s = new Screen();
try {
    s.find("screenshot.jpg");
} catch (FindFailed e) {

}
```

I keep getting cannot find errors.

error message:

> FindFailed: can not find /Users/ealiaj/Desktop/Automation/workspace/WheelsUp - IOS/screenshot1.jpg in S(0)[0,0 1440x900]
>     Line 2189, in file Region.java

[image: Image trying to find]
This is the image on the screen, The large red rectangle is the image I have created a screenshot for and try to find, but get that error.

The only thing I am able to successfully find is that gray rectangle, or at least it doesn't throw an error for.

Comment: You can do this without using Sikuli. Create function in appium which capture screen shot of particular element (what you want to verify ) save it  in you system at run time. And match with your base image file using Java code.

Comment: Can you please provide sample code? Thanks

Comment: can you post the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: updated in original post

Comment: @SadikAli I am also interested in the way you showed in your comment. Can you please add a sample or link to any (documentation) source ?

Comment: Are you able to find element of locator of images which you want to verify? If yes please reply, so I can prepare some code which will help you.

Comment: @SadikAli Yes I am able to find locators for the elements. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone know how to achieve this in plain Java or sikuli?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method to verify images:

```
@Test
public void verifyImages() {    

    //WebElement img = driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.ImageView");

   //take screen shot
    File screen = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                        .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);


    //capture image of searched contact icon
    List<WebElement > imageList = driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.ImageView' and @index='0']");
    System.out.println(imageList.size());

    System.out.println(i);
    WebElement image = imageList.get(1);
    Point point = image.getLocation();

    //get element dimension
    int width = image.getSize().getWidth();
    int height = image.getSize().getHeight();

    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(screen);
    BufferedImage dest = img.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), width,
                                                                 height);
    ImageIO.write(dest, "png", screen);
    File file = new File("Menu.png");
    FileUtils.copyFile(screen, file);

    //verify images
    verifyImage("Menu.png", "Menu.png" );
}



public void verifyImage(String image1, String image2) throws IOException{
    File fileInput = new File(image1);
    File fileOutPut = new File(image2);

    BufferedImage bufileInput = ImageIO.read(fileInput);
    DataBuffer dafileInput = bufileInput.getData().getDataBuffer();
    int sizefileInput = dafileInput.getSize();                     
    BufferedImage bufileOutPut = ImageIO.read(fileOutPut);
    DataBuffer dafileOutPut = bufileOutPut.getData().getDataBuffer();
    int sizefileOutPut = dafileOutPut.getSize();
    Boolean matchFlag = true;
    if(sizefileInput == sizefileOutPut) {                         
       for(int j=0; j<sizefileInput; j++) {
             if(dafileInput.getElem(j) != dafileOutPut.getElem(j)) {
                   matchFlag = false;
                   break;
             }
        }
    }
    else                            
       matchFlag = false;
    Assert.assertTrue(matchFlag, "Images are not same");    
 }
```

Comment: Does this verify that two images are exactly the same? I am trying to find an image within the screen. For example to find a button in the whole image. Thanks

Comment: yes, it does find the two images which are exactly same. I used it to test 2 images on my side and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, to be clear, I have image1 which is the whole screen, and image2 which is a button, this will find image2 inside of image1?

Comment: Yes, just pass the locator like in my code i am trying to match the contact icon in the whole screen.

Comment: Test it and if you run with problem, i will help you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I use VerifyImage for a single image correct? Or do I need to use both methods?

Comment: Well verifyImage is a method where you pass the two images to verify. And second method "verifyImages" is the test which u pass the locator and get the screenshots to verify the images.

Comment: Ok will mess around with it, and let you know if i need any help. Thanks

Comment: Hey I see that this takes a screenshot of the element, what If i have the file stored locally already how can I use that instead. Thanks

Comment: First it takes the screenshot at run time and it compares it with the image you have in your project to compare against. Look at the verifyImage method, you pass 2 images. First one, you get from screenshot and second one you have stored in project

Comment: For verifyImage("Menu.png", "Menu.png" ); can I put the filepath to the file?

Comment: try it...You have to figure out some stuff by yourself..i can help you when you get stuck but first try and test it. Understand the code carefully.

Comment: Just tried it, but this is not what I want. This is basically creating a screenshot of an element, and then comparing it to make sure both images are the same. I have some text images, that are in 2-3 different elements. I need to take a screenshot of the whole screen, and find an image within. This only compares that 2 screenshots are identical, which they are not, since Screen 1 is the whole screen and screen 2 is an element.

Comment: @Elsid yes just modify it as per your needs. I gave you the code where you can modify it as per your needs. Should be simple for you

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that is the program looking a .PNG file, and in your code your are putting a .JPG file.

Comment: Sorry that was copied from when I changed the filetype to .PNG it is .PNG is both.